# How to clone a node to appear exactly on top in a different pane

Tags: javafx-8

In my (full-screen) program I have several items displayed in a layout. What I would like to do is that when I tap or click on a item is to show a full screen editor. The idea is to have transition from the item shown to the editor.

When the editor is shown I first display a semi-transparent view on top of the stackpane, underneath the other items are still visible. The selected item should 'move' to the upper layer, and then start to transform to its editor shape. Closing the editor should of course be a reverse course of actions.

The first attempt was to move the from its container to the upper layer, but JavaFX complained about the bound properties. I rather not have to code a whole bunch of bind/unbinds, so I assumed this was not the route.

My next attempt was something like this:

```
private volatile FullScreenService fullscreenService;

private void showFullPhoto(MouseEvent e) {

    FullScreenService service = fullscreenService;
    if (service != null) {
        try {
            Node node = (Node) e.getSource();
            ImageView photoView = (ImageView)node.lookup("#image");
            Image image = photoView.getImage();

            Pane pane = new Pane();
            pane.setPrefSize(1920d, 1080d);
            ImageView copy = new ImageView(image);
            copy.setRotate(node.getRotate());
            node.setVisible(false);
            Bounds bounds = photoView.localToScene(photoView.getBoundsInLocal());
            copy.setLayoutX(bounds.getMinX());
            copy.setLayoutY(bounds.getMinY());
            pane.getChildren().add(copy);
            service.requestFullScreen(pane);
        } catch (InUseException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to hide the original view and 'clone' the part that should be shown (and then transitioned). In this case I extract the image part out of a photo (that also has a border and caption), and make a copy on the editor screen.

However the location of the image does not match the original location exactly, it is off by a couple of pixels, making the image 'jump'.

I've created the pane to be exact the size of the screen, so I thought I could assume scene coordinates are the same as the new node's coordinates.

Abstracting my question: given two overlapping panes, how to make sure a node is exactly on top of another node?

Comment: Maybe [study this layout demo](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1441960).  I don't know if it would help you, it's a long shot, but perhaps...

Comment: Thanks, your demo shows the little differences between the various bound methods, maybe that's the problem.